# Get sensor value OnClick

Tags: java, android

I can have light sensor data displaying all the time using

```
   public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    float lux = event.values[0];
    Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    myButton.setText(String.valueOf(lux));
```

However, i want it to only display 1 value everytime i click the button, i was trying

```
public void buttonOnClick(View v) {
    Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    myButton.setText(String.valueOf(lux));
```

Whith var lux declared in the beguinning of the class

```
public float lux;
```

However, it's showing me only 0.0.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Can you print the value before you set it please? Seems like setting the text isn't the problem.

Comment: I am not sure how strict Android is with messing with UI Elements outside of the `runOnUIThread` thread... Can you post more work with your OnClickListener and the code that retrieves and interacts with the sensor?

Comment: remove `float` from `onSensorChanged`. Leave only `lux = event.values[0];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning event.values[0] to a new flaot (and not to the member variable declared at the beginning of the class). Change your onSensorChanged like this:

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
  lux = event.values[0];
  Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
  myButton.setText(String.valueOf(lux));
}
```

By the way, it is better design to declare member variable private. But that is another story.